# How passing properly parameters value in HttpPost Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to submit the value of the submit button that was clicked to a controller method but the parameter in the method is not being bound to the value of the clicked button.

**View**

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="TEST"  />
    <input type="submit" name="test" value="TEST22" />
}
```

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string action)
{
    // the value of action is null
    ....
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Could I use the attribute "HttpParamAction" in any way?

Comment: I have two buttons in the same Html.BeginForm()...I need to know which button the user Clicked...I don't think your workaround is good for me!!!  ;(

With one button to perform Save data staying in the same page, with other Button perform Save data and to handle redirect to another page, but this I'd like to manage in the View. Many Thanks

Comment: Stephen write the answer so I mark it as good

Comment: I have deleted all my previous comments since they related to the original question which was completely different from what it is now. Suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form will submit the name/value pairs (based on the `name` and `value` attributes) of successful controls. In the case of an `<input type="submit" ... />`, it will be the value of the button that was clicked (values of other submit buttons will not be submitted).

In your case, you are giving the buttons a `name="test"` attribute which means the form will submit either `test: TEST` or `test: TEST22` (depending on which button you clicked) so therefore the POST method must be

```
public ActionResult Index(string test)
```

alternatively, you could change each button to have `name="action"`

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen...got it! :)